# Mocking interface repository

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am supposed to mock a repository written by someone else.

I have an interface `IUserDetailsRepository` that just Queries the database to retrieve user details(`finduser()`) stored in it manually( not through create user method). The method `finduser()` is implemented in helper class and is used by service class. This class has getuser() method in which `finduser()` is called. How do I mock this? Should I mock service class and call `getuser()` or do I have to mock helper class and called `finduser()` method of repository?

I am stuck with this.. since I don't have createuser how do I mock the object and inject. I am totally confused. Please help me.

If any such programming structure is explained on how to mock, that would be of great help.

Here are the codes

```
 **********IUserDetails Repository************

@Repository
public interface IUserDetails 
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserEntity,String>
{
    @Query("select ud.id,ud.name,ud.unit from UserEntity u where ud.id=:id and ud.passwd=:passwd")
    List<Object[]> findUserbyID(@Param("id") String id, @Param("passwd") String passwd);
}


*****UserHelper class*****
@Component
public class UserHelper{
@Autowired 
private IUserDetails repo;
@Transactional(rollbackFor=(Exception.class);
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
publib List<UserDetailsDTO> findUserbyID(String id, String passwd)
{
List<UserDetailsDTO> user=new ArrayList<UserDetailsDTO>();
List<Object[]> repouser=repo.findUserbyID(id,passwd);
UserDetailsDTO udto=new UserDetailsDTO();
for(Object[] ob:repouser)
{
udto.setid((String)ob[0]));
udto.setname((String)ob[1]));
udto.setunit((String)ob[2]));
user.add(udto);
}
return user;
}

*********UserDetailsDTO ********
public class UserDetailsDTO implements Serializable{
private String id,name,unit,passwd;
    public String setid(String id)
    {this.id=id;}
    public String setpasswd(String passwd)
    {this.passwd=passwd;}
    public String setname(String name)
    {this.name=name;}
    public String setunit(String unit)
    {this.unit=unit;}
    public String getid()
    {return id;}
    public String getname()
    {return name;}
    public String getunit()
    {return unit;}
    public String getpasswd()
    {return passwd;}
}


*********UserDetailsService********
public class UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired 
    private UserHelper helper;
    public List<UserDetailsDTO> getUser(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("passwd") String passwd)
    {
        List<UserDetailsDTO> udto=new ArrayList<UserDetailsDTO>();
        udto=helper.findUserbyID(id,passwd);
        if(udto==null)
        throw new UserNotFound(id);
    return udto;
    }
}


************Test class**********
Importing junit and mockito related packages;
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserDetailsTest{

@InjectMocks
UserDetailsService service;

@Mock
IUserDetails rep;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void TestFindUser()
{
    UserDetailsDTO details=new UserDetailsDTO();
    detail.setid("123");
    details.setpasswd("p@wd");
    details.sename("MyName");
    details.setunit("Engg");

    Mockito.when(rep.findUserbyId("123","p@wd")).thenReturn(details);  
    // Throws me error related to mismatch return types
    //when i change it to thenReturn((List<Object[]>)details), it throws error that it is not able to stub

    List<UserDetailsDTO> ud=serrvice.getUser("123","p@wd");
    asserThat(ud,is(notNullValue()));
    assertEquals(ud,details);
}
}
```

Comment: Probably adding some code with actual method signatures will simplify others understanding your problem

Comment: Hi @SergGr , I edited my post and added the code. Also added my test code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `UserDetailsService` perspective, you do not need to mock the `IUserDetails`, but `UserHelper`:

```
public class UserDetailsTest{

@InjectMocks
UserDetailsService service;

@Mock
UserHelper helperMock;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void TestFindUser()
{
    UserDetailsDTO details=new UserDetailsDTO();
    detail.setid("123");
    details.setpasswd("p@wd");
    details.sename("MyName");
    details.setunit("Engg");

    List<UserDetailsDTO> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(details);

    Mockito.when(helperMock.findUserbyID("123","p@wd")).thenReturn(userList);  

    List<UserDetailsDTO> resultUserList=serrvice.getUser("123","p@wd");
    asserThat(ud,is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat("Size", userList.size(), equalTo(resultUserList.size());
    assertEquals("Details",details, equalTo(resultUserList.get(0)));
}
```

The scenario that you were trying to achieve would have its place in the `UserHelper` test class:

```
    public class UserHelperTest{

    @InjectMocks
    UserHelper userHelper;

    @Mock
    IUSerDetails repo;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFindUserById()
    {
        String id = "id";
        String name = "name";
        String unit = "unit";
        String passwd = ""passwd";

        List<Object[]> queryResult = new ArrayList<>(); 
        queryResult.add(new Object[]{id,name,unit});

        Mockito.when(repo.findUserByID(id,passwd)).thenReturn(queryResult));

        List<UserDetailsDTO> resultList = userHelper.findUserbyID(id,passwd);

        // assertions on size and content of first element..
```

Comment: Thank You.. This is a great help. Will try to work on this. If you can further explain a little on why you have written mock on class and interface in two different classes that will help me.

Comment: You can mock an interface or a class. And i have split the tests because you should not invoke code of direct dependencies.. thats why i mock UserHelper from the Service test.. i does not care what is inside of UserHelper (which uses the Repo interface).. the Repo would be important only for the UserHelper class. Hope that helps

Comment: Hint: there is no need to use @Before with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` when you are already using the mockito runner. Either runner **or** initMocks(); both do the *same* thing!

Comment: I am again getting the same error as before at thenReturn(details) as the method thenReturn(List<UserDetailsDTO>) in the type OngoingStubbing <List<UserDetailsDTO>> is not applicable for arguments (UserDetailsDTO). I in fact tried casting the type to List<userDetailsDTO>, this gives me a new error.  "Unfinished stubbing detected here:"

Comment: Ok i got it.. I passed userList to theReturn() instead of details and it worked

Comment: Yes .. my copy / paste mistake.. anyway glad it worked for you

Comment: Thank You :) I have read this somewhere that Mockito tests are written to  always show success results no matter what. Is this true? because i changed Id to 12 in one test class and tried to run. it still showed me test successful. I mean no failures

Comment: If you set the details.id to whatever.. it does not matter.. but if you put this helperMock.findUserbyID("12","p@wd")) and run this serrvice.getUser("123","p@wd"); then your test will fail. And no .. mockito is not wiritten to pass all your tests.. in fact your need to usually sweat a lot to make it go green. Cheers